# Is it possible to explicitly define valid parameter values for a web service operation within a WSDL?

Tags: xml, web-services, xsd, wsdl

I'm working with a web service that defines its API in a WSDL. Is it possible to specify the exact values which are valid for the parameters of each operation?

E.g. suppose the web service exposes an operation called "setStatus" that expects one parameter called "status". The only valid options for "status" are "EMPLOYEE" and "CONTRACTOR". Is there a way to explicitly define these two values inside of the WSDL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WSDL contains an XML Schema in its `<types>` section and in XML Schema you can use an [enumeration](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dt-enumeration) to constrain the set of allowed values.

For example, you might declare your `status` parameter as having this type:

```
<xsd:simpleType name="StatusType">
  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
    <xsd:enumeration value="EMPLOYEE" />
    <xsd:enumeration value="CONTRACTOR" />
  </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```